# Which pattern to use?

Tags: java, pdf, design-patterns, plugins, code-reuse

**Problem:**

I have to fill up PDF forms. The same fields have to be filled up using different formats for the value. For example there can be a date field like @today_date@ or @today_date_in_words@. Similary @number@ or @number_in_words@.

Then there comes times frequently where requests come for more formats for the same fields.

My question is, can I handle this using some pattern so that I will not need to do lot of changes to the code, rather I can just plug the new format and it gives me the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's surprising that most of the design problems can be solved using a simple abstraction.

First create an interface called Formatter :

```
public interface Formatter<I,O> {
    public O format(I input);
}
```

Then create a concrete implementation of the formatter for converting numbers to words :

```
    public class NumberInWordsFormatter implements Formatter<Number,String> {

    @Override
    public String format(Number input) {
        String numberInWords = input.toString();
        //logic for converting a number to words
        return numberInWords;
    }

}
```

This is how you can use the above classes :

```
public class FormattingExamples {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Formatter<Number,String> formatter = new NumberInWordsFormatter();
        String numberInWords = formatter.format(100);
        System.out.println(numberInWords);
    }
}
```

You can create a series of formatters and use them to format your fields in different formats. Note that in the current example, I simply convert the number to a String and return it. You can implement the logic to read the number and convert it into words in the format method. Also note that the class that holds your field name and value should be passed a Formatter. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So it will mean I will have to add different formatter class each time there is a new format requested? Can i dynamically enter the format pattern and get it applied to a particular field?

Comment: Yes. You will need to create different formatter classes. For example, to convert a number in words to int, create a new formatter called WordsToNumber. To decide which formatter to use at runtime, you can implement a simple factory that creates the appropriate formatter for you when passed a format string.